# Using lodash in shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is this considered a best practice? Or is there a better solution to prevent needless rerendering?

I am trying to render thousands of rows. Each row has many cells. But I have pretty hard time preventing bottlenecks when I update not related state in one of my reducers.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'

import Cell from './Cell'

export class Row extends Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate (newProps) {
    return !_.isEqual(newProps.item, this.props.item)
  }

  componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('row is updated!')
  }

  render () {
    const { item } = this.props

    return (
      <div className='rowek'>
        {item.map((i, key) => <Cell key={key} item={i}/>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Row
```

Comment: I have a similar structure and i use shouldComponentUpdate as well.

Comment: Yeah that's normal, if you're using an up to date version of React, you can use `class Row extends PureComponent` which does precisely this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar experience building a calendar where every date contains async data.

My recommendations:

- ShouldComponentUpdate can slow down the performance of your app, the default behavior of react is already good enough to handle this situations and avoid re-rendering when the data hasn't changed.
  Also you can take a look at: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent
- Test if your application is actually slow in a production env. (minified files, no action loggers, etc).
- `key={key}` I wont trust this as the key of my cell, try to prepend the number of the row or something more specific.
- Is there a way you can actually map every cell directly with a property on the state? (I don't know the design of your state)

@Cell.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, { index }) => ({
    item: selectItemByCellIndex(index),
});
```

Comment: I could use direct reference but I also want to filter the rows and do some other logic. ImmutableJs is probably the only answer?

Comment: I don't think ImmutableJs will make this better, since your state will still represent changes, try to reference directly the row to a part of your state, is what I did in the calendar scenario, my dates just iterate over the data that belongs to its week.

Comment: It does not really help me but I appreciate your time. I should have posted more examples. :/